# Is there a way to run a TestNG test for a particular class in IntelliJ without compiling the entire project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

I have working project, If I write any new test case with TestNG framework until I compile the entire project it's not getting compiled.
Even for a small fix, I have to compile the entire project.

Is there a way to compile specific class and run quickly ?

Comment: [Duplicate question. testng.xml add exclude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21136285/13173387)

Comment: Have you tried to run "Build | Compile" for a new class?